# Show measure only when another filter is active

Tags: powerbi

I'm very new to Power BI, so please be kind as I'm trying my best to learn.
I'm creating a measure that shows the average of all historic data from a given instrument (I can select the instrument from a chart in the dashboard).
The thing is: the average has meaning only when I select one instrument. When two or more instruments are selected, I don't want to show the average.
The average is calculated by data on a table that has the columns: `Instrument_ID`, `date`, `time`, `elevation` (that's the column where I calculate the average).
Can someone give me directions of what to do please? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please show us your code, if you have any.

Comment: I don't have much yet, only a single line calculating the average:
avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(table[elevation])).
I also have a line graph where i can select the instrument i want to see.
I know that the calculate function can have filters and i want to put a filter that: if we select one instrument on the graph, the avg shows the instrument average elevation; if two or more instruments are selected, the avg doesn't show anything (or something like null or not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, with two methods,

1. Set the slicer to only allow one value selection
   or
2. Check if the slicer only has one value selected using HASONEVALUE

Your DAX will have to be wrapped with an IF statement, and assuming that the slicer is using the 'Instrument_ID'

Your measure = IF(HASONEVALUE(tablename'Instrument_ID'), CALCULATE(AVERAGE(table[elevation])), BLANK())

You are not doing a compare in your IF statement, as HASONEVALUE will return a True/False. If the selected item only has one value, then it will return your measure, else in this case blank.

Comment: I used the second method and it worked! I will try to figure the first one as (I think) it's the easisest way, but i honestly don't have the knowledge to understand it yet. Thank you for your help!